# Find out dimension of the eigenspace of a given linear transformation $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $T:\mathbb{R^4}\rightarrow \mathbb{R^{4}}$ be defined by $T(x,y,z,w)=(x+y+5w,x+2y+w,-z+2w,5x+y+2z)$ then what would be the dimension of the eigenspace of $T$?

One approach may be to find out eigenvalues and then eigenvectors.
Is there any other approach that will consume less amount of time
and calculation?

Comment: Which eigenspace are you talking about? There's an eigenspace associated to each eigenvalue.

Comment: Number of linearly independent eigen vectors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[A nonsingular real $n\times n$ symmetric matrix has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Symmetric_matrices)

Comment: I didnt get your point? Did you mean given linear transformation is symmetric nonsingular?

Comment: Yes... did you hope to get through without examining the actual transformation? :) Write it down fast!

Comment: It is clear that symmetric matrices are orthogonally diagonalizable. Then no need to find out domension of eigen space it would be 4. I wanted to know in case of ordinary matrix? thanks

Comment: If you want to ask the question about general matrices, then no, there is no easy answer. After all, for $n\geq 5$ you are trying to solve a polynomial in a single variable of degree 5 or more! This is by no means simple...

Comment: But isn't it that we have to mention , eigenspace is corresponding to which eigenvalue, I mean does the question makes sense without mentioning to which eigenvalue??

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana I thought the poster intended to find the dimension of each eigenspace, from the comments they included.

Comment: Well I also have a feeling that  it might be a possiblity but I am not cent percent sure that's why I asked. @rschweib

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana You saw the comment by the OP, right?  *Number of linearly independent eigen vectors? – srijan May 10 '12 at 13:39*  Sounds like that's what they were looking for, in the end.

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana Whether *what* is true?

Comment: @rschwieb whether it is true that if we are not given to corresponding which eigenvaluer we have to find the eigenvector then we find all the eigenvector possibly LI.???

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana The comment by the person who wrote the question left would seem to indicate *no*, which was the point I was trying to make earlier. Also they accepted the answer, so it must have been what they wanted.